# Streaming video using VLC media player to anywhere

Tags: video, streaming, vlc-media-player, rtsp

I want to stream a video over the local network from VLC and the receiver must be able to play it on a device using the given URL, *not* necessarily other VLC.

Like you would open a stream link in any default player or even any browser that opens the player appropriately.

Say I want to play the video by entering the URL into say my Android's default browser window and it automatically opens MX Player or something to play it.

How can I achieve  that with VLC?

Please do not recommend other VLC players or dedicated apps.

Comment: That question is too broad to be answerable. The choice of streaming technology depends on your specific use case. Since no good answers have come since 2013, I suggest closing this question.

Answer (score -2):

Use that html code to view your rtsp . Chance the ip adres and rady to go

test1900